# str_replac() dynamic data

Tags: php

So, I'm busy with a little program, and I want to replace some data. But the data is dynamic.

I have the string `Warm Bodies (2013)` and I want to get rid of (2013)
Only `Warm Bodies` can be everything, and `(2013)` can be everything for example
`Warm Bodies (1999)` or `a random string (2011)` So the data I want to delete is always between ().

I thought i can do this with `str_replace("(%?%), "", "Warm Bodies (2013)");` but I can't find a good solution.

Comment: preg_replace and use a regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you only want to replace the last group of parentheses in your title, in that case you don't need to use a regular expression, just cut the string after the last opening parenthesis.

```
$title = "Warm Bodies (2013)";
$newTitle = substr($title, 0, strrpos($title, "(") - 1);
```

Comment: IMHO a regex is simpler here. And faster. ;)

Comment: Hmm, tested again, apparently they are almost equally, but yours was a bit faster on 1'000 iterations.

Comment: Ohh thanks, this works good! Because it;s not always a number

Answer (score 3):

Use `preg_replace` ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php. This will replace the pattern with new string

```
preg_replace("/\(\d+\)/","",$str);
```

If it is not a number :

```
preg_replace("/\(.*\)/","",$str);
```

Comment: that's why you should take a look at my example

Comment: Edited the answer, Now it will match even if it is not a number

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "Warm Bodies (2013)";
$result = preg_replace('/\([^\)]+\)/', '', $string);
```

or, to also remove white spaces surrounding brackets:

```
$string = "Warm Bodies (2013)";
$result = preg_replace('/\s*\([^\)]+\)\s*/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should nicely do it:

```
$strings = array(
    'Warm Bodies (2013)',
    'Warm Bodies (1999)',
    'a random string (2011)',
);

$pattern = '/\s*\(\d+\)/';
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $output = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
    var_dump($output);
}
```

The output generated is as follows:

```
string(11) "Warm Bodies"
string(11) "Warm Bodies"
string(15) "a random string"
```

You can also use the following code instead of the loop if you have an array with values to replace:

```
$output = preg_replace($pattern, '', $strings);
var_dump($output);
```

This generates the following array:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(11) "Warm Bodies"
  [1]=> string(11) "Warm Bodies"
  [2]=> string(15) "a random string"
}
```